# Passing dynamic filename using curl in java

Tags: java, curl

I wrote the Java code for calling curl command by sending post json file as request. My question is how to pass dynamic file name in curl command through java call.

```
curl -X POST https://reqbin.com/echo/post/json
     -H "Content-Type: application/json" 
     -d "@filename.json"
```

Here I need to pass filename dynamically but getting bad request when I passed hard-coded filename it's working fine.

Tried below option in java.

"-d", "@filename.json" - working fine.

Dynamically tried below two options.

```
"-d","@"+file.getAbsolutePath()
"-d","@D:\\sourcePath\\"+filename.json
```

Both the above command getting bad request.

Comment: What exactly do you like to solve by running curl from Java? why dont you just use a Java HTTP Client (or a high level wrapper like the Spring RestTemplate)

Comment: Paste the generated curl string which is giving bad request

Comment: @JensBaitinger I used below Apache client code for making two way SSL but getting "Remote host closed connection".             //keyStore file
   System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", "D:\\Own comany JKS file.jks");
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", "password"); // Password given by vendor
   //TrustStore file
   System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore","D:\\Client certificate JKS file.jks");
   System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", "password");

Comment: @satyesht Used given curl command. ProcessBuilder process = new ProcessBuilder(
    "curl.exe",
             "-XPOST",
             "-H", "Authorization:Basic header value",
             "-H", "Content-Type:application/json",
             "URL",
             "--cert" ,"D:\\publickey.pem",
             "--key", "D:\\privatekey.key",
             "--cacert" ,"D:\\client public key.cer",
             "-d","@D:\\"+f.getName()+""
         );

Comment: Add -v for verbose in curl to get detailed error ,also in instead of passing File name you can pass -d 'file contents' somthing like -d Files.readAllbytes(new Path(filepath))

Comment: Thank u satyesht..sorry for late response.